# Error only with firefox on deployed version on heroku

Tags: heroku, meteor

This problem made me crazy, and it's stealing me a lot of time.

My Meteor application work good on my local dev machine, but when I deploy it with BUILD_PACK=https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git I have a problem **ONLY** with Firefox, that give me a generic error

```
"Exception from Deps afterFlush function function: "
```

...but I can't view call stack or where is generated.

I check that build pack and local dev machine use the same node.js version (v0.10.26), obviously on local use Meteor integrated MongoDB and on heroku use Mongolab service.

I don't know how find the problem.

On heroku build version Chrome work like a charm, **Firefox have that the problem**.
On local machine both **Chrome and Firefox work good**.

I have also tried with demeteorize, but the problem is the same...

edit:

On Firefox debug console error is on row 1 (43c9ee3da328e93321624a3179d27858c654879d.js:1)

How can I deploy on heroku without js minify?

edit2:

I have deployed on *.metor.com and **WORK GOOD**! (with and without --debug flag)
The problem/error is heroku and/or build pack...but where?!?

SOLUTION FINDED:

I have made a big mistake. The error throw from an external library. This library give this problem only on firefox.

Firefox console debug log don't reports the library error, because the call to this API library it is done into observer method.

The problem exist on both heroku and local dev machine...I'm feeling very silly

thanks guy for your support ad time!

Comment: Are you using the appcache package? I ask only because there is some mention in the Meteor documentation of appcache not working with Firefox (and that is the only Firefox-specific problem mentioned in the docs).

Comment: no, I don't use appcache :(

Answer (score 1):

This error is from your client side code, the way its deployed isn't likely to change it (Demeteorizer, using meteor deploy instead, etc)

These errors usually come from you reading data without it being ready yet. On your localhost the latency is so low usually data is immediately ready and you wouldn't notice the problem.

This is an example of code that can cause such an issue:

```
var firstname = People.findOne().name;
```

Here the assumption is that the people collection is ready. If its not ready `People.findOne()` returns `null` and looking for `.name` is going to throw an Error while loading a page.

To fix this you have to find where you have used code like the above (obviously yours will have different names and structure) and check that the collection is ready first, or that the result being searched for actually exists.

Again this is just the most likely place the error comes from. There are plenty of other reasons that can cause the error. Firefox's debug console isn't very descriptive as Chrome's is so its quite difficult to debug.

It could even be a 3rd party dependency didn't load and you tried to use it somewhere like a template helper.

Comment: thank for your exhaustive explain. But I use waitOn features of iron-router package. The collections is all ready.
I have also insert a delay in publish function (on server side) for simulate remote working, but on local dev machine all work good...also with delay.
I'm asking me why on Chrome work, but don't on Firefox?!?
You have right: Firefox debug console isn't very descriptive...

Comment: I am having the same issue, and it is only in Firefox! Why Firefox, have you solved it?